# label not displayed in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I try to modify this script in python 3.6, but I have a problem about a label isn't displayed at the bottom .here is the code :

```
from tkinter import *

def sel():
    global selection
    if value==1:#value and var1 are in radiobutton R1
        selection = "You selected the option " + str(var1.get())
    elif value==2:#value and var2 are in radiobutton R2
        selection = "You selected the option " + str(var2.get())
    elif value==3:#value and var3 are in radiobutton R3
        selection = "You selected the option " + str(var3.get())
    label.config(text = selection)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x250')
value=IntVar()
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()

R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var1, value=1,
                  command=sel)
R1.pack( anchor = W )

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var2, value=2,
                  command=sel)
R2.pack( anchor = W )

R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3", variable=var3, value=3,
                  command=sel)
R3.pack( anchor = W)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

when I choose one of the radiobuttons, normally the label should appear below, but is not displayed at the bottom of the radiobutton and there is this error:

NameError: name 'selection' is not defined

Comment: You can either declare `selection` in the global scope or change `global selection` to `selection = ""` inside `sel()`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of "value" never changes. And this means that the function you call never gives selection any value. Since selection has no value but you use it anyways you get an nameError.

I would prefer using lambda in the button commands like this:

```
from tkinter import *

def sel(value):
    selection = "You selected the option {}".format(value)
    label.configure(text=selection)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x250')
selection = "StartText"
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1",command=lambda: sel(1))
R1.pack()
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2",command=lambda: sel(2))
R2.pack()
R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3",command=lambda: sel(3))
R3.pack()

label = Label(root, text=selection)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```